# Pandas set date as day(int)-month(str)-year(int)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to change the formatting of a date column

original: 2020/05/22

Desired outcome: **22/may/2020**

so far I've done:

`.to_datetime`

`dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')`

converting into: 22/05/2020

how can I get the middle part to convert into alphabetical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, all the format codes are given here [date formats](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%d/%b/%Y')
print(df)

          Date
0  22/May/2020
```

Comment: thank you! worked like a charm. Any idea what the %b stands for?